# Restrict view access of a Phabricator (Maniphest) Task field to only a specific group of users?

Tags: phabricator, maniphest

On our company's Phabricator site, for example, I have an Approver select (dropdown) field that is part of the form when I create a new Task. I want only a specific group of people to be able to see this Approver field when someone creates a new Task or edits the Task. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create forms for creating maniphest tasks and pre fill them with values. Therefore go to `https://<phabricator-uri/transactions/editengine/maniphest.task/` .
You can additionally set permissions to different groups to grant access to these forms.

For more details just read: `https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/forms/`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately, we tried that solution but found that even after using using "Custom Policy" and setting it to only show the field to a few select users, the field is still visible to all admin users on our site. Is there any way to hide the field from users that happen to be admins?